# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'id' cannot be null in

Tags: php, pdo

I want to ask. I encountered an error

**Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE [23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'id' can not be null in C: \ WTServer \ WWW \ disc \ admin \ newsadd.php: 79 Stack trace: # 0 C: \ WTServer \ WWW \ disc \ admin \ newsadd.php (79): PDOStatement-> execute () # 1 {play} thrown in C: \ WTServer \ WWW \ disc \ admin \ newsadd.php on line 79**

happens when I add a foreign key in the database
I do not know what I should do, so far I have not found the right coding

Foreign Key (id) from tbl_login

my code newsadd.php

```
        if(!isset($errMSG))
    {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_news(newsid,id, newstitle,newsauthor,newsimg,newscontent) VALUES(:unews, :idlogin, :utitle, :uauthor, :uimg, :ucontent)');
        $stmt->bindParam(':unews',$newsid);
        $stmt->bindParam(':idlogin',$id);
        $stmt->bindParam(':utitle',$newstitle);
        $stmt->bindParam(':uauthor',$newsauthor);

        $stmt->bindParam(':uimg',$newsimg);

        $stmt->bindParam(':ucontent',$newscontent);

        if($stmt->execute())
        {
            $successMSG = "new record succesfully inserted ...";
            header("refresh:5;news.php"); // redirects image view page after 5 seconds.
        }
        else
        {
            $errMSG = "error while inserting....";
        }
    }
}
```

?>

error in line 79 **if($stmt->execute())**
* Sorry for my bad english

Comment: It means that `$id` is null in `$stmt->bindParam(':idlogin',$id);`. You should var dump it and make sure the var is set correctly

Comment: id column is not set null. but if i set null id column, data will save but id NULL.

Answer (score -1):

It maybe, trying to write data in the same field (for unique id field)

Comment: how? i dont get it